# ChromeDriver : 'Puppeteer's LaunchAsync' not working in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer, windows-console

In the C# console application, the following command is not working

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions());
```

When debugger come to the above code suddenly stops the execution.
Here is my full code

```
try {
 await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
 var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions());
 var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
 await page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.com");
 await page.ScreenshotAsync(@ "C:\Temp\doc.png");
 return "success";
} catch (Exception e) {
 Console.WriteLine(e);
 throw;
}
```

Comment: did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't receive any error. Try catch block didn't generate any error.

Comment: i have a feeling you may need to use a background worker if you are using .net `core` console

Comment: No. I am using .net 4.6.1 version and working with normal .net codes , not core

Comment: Can you try catching more exceptions (All C++, CLR , Win32) -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017 and see your code breaks on the correct line ?

Comment: Got it. The exception is 'Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in 'F:\Projects\NewChromeTest\NewChromeTest\bin\Debug\NewChromeTest.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The assembly with display name 'Newtonsoft.Json' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified'.

Comment: @Jevgeni Geurtsen After adding Newtonsoft.Json it again stops at the same command, this time no exception happens. I enabled all exception in settings.

Comment: What version of the Newtonsoft library did you add? Its asking specifically to use `10.0.0.0`, did you add the corresponding library?

Comment: Yes. But didn't worked

Comment: Did you add a local project reference or did you re-add the Nu-Get package, as that packages usually comes into a project through Nu-Get?

Comment: I added it through NuGet.